# How can I check whether the current buffer is an eshell buffer?

Tags: window, eshell

I'm trying to write a function which opens or closes an eshell window. So far I have:

```lisp
    (defun bottom-window-eshell()
      (interactive)
      (let ((buf (eshell)))
        (switch-to-buffer (other-buffer buf))
        (switch-to-buffer-other-window buf)))
```

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Please pose only one question per post. Thx.

Comment: If you want a single eshell window which you can bring to the front at any time, you might try https://github.com/4DA/eshell-toggle.  I haven't used it, but I use `vterm-toggle` and I presume it's similar.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you're asking, but maybe something like this helps?

```lisp
(defun bottom-window-eshell()
  (interactive)
  (unless (eq major-mode 'eshell-mode)
    (switch-to-buffer-other-window (eshell))))
```